# Who calls configureGlobal function? How call configureGlobal function?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a question while studying Spring Security.

To set up `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`, I used `configureGlobal` method with `@Autowired`.

I heard that the `configurationGlboal` function name can be anything (even whatever!)

**Who calls the `configureGlobal` function? How does it call this if the function name might be different?**

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.company.mypackage" })
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
          .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring calls that method, because it is marked as autowired, see [`Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html):

> **Autowired Methods**
>
> Config methods may have an arbitrary name and any number of arguments; each of those arguments will be autowired with a matching bean in the Spring container. Bean property setter methods are effectively just a special case of such a general config method. Such config methods do not have to be public.

But for Spring Security you also have to annotate your class, see [`EnableGlobalAuthentication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configuration/EnableGlobalAuthentication.html):

> Annotations that are annotated with `EnableGlobalAuthentication` also signal that the annotated class can be used to configure a global instance of `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. For example:
>
> ```java
> @Configuration
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class MyWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>        @Autowired
>        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
>                auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
>                            .and().withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
>        }
>
>        // Possibly overridden methods ...
> }
> ```
>
> The following annotations are annotated with `EnableGlobalAuthentication`
>
> - `EnableWebSecurity`
> - `EnableWebMvcSecurity`
> - `EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`
>
> Configuring `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` in a class without the `EnableGlobalAuthentication` annotation has unpredictable results.